# Check if string contains an element from array ignoring case (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string

I have this code to get the string I need to check against

```
var f = document.getElementsByClassName('first');
var c = f[0];
var xx = c.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
var chk = xx.innerText;
```

And an array

```
const ar = ["[Text]", "[More]", "[AnotherText]", "[Stuff]", "[Yes]"]
```

The string (`chk`) in question can contain any of the values from that array, and can be any case

Example: `[TExT] some random text afterwards`

What I need is to check if `chk` contains any of the values from `ar`, ignoring the case

Tried

```
if (ar.some(chk => chk.toLowerCase().includes(chk))){console.log("yay")}
```

or

```
if (ar.some(chk.includes.bind(chk)))
```

but they return undefined

Comment: `chk => chk.toLowerCase().includes(chk)` change your variable names.

Comment: Don't use the same variable `chk` for the callback parameter and the search string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change from

```
chk => chk.toLowerCase().includes(chk)
```

to

```
val => val.toLowerCase().includes(chk.toLowerCase())
```

or

```js
const ar = ["[Text]", "[More]", "[AnotherText]", "[Stuff]", "[Yes]"];

const isContain = (arr, chk) =>
  arr.some(
    (val) =>
      val.toLowerCase().includes(chk.toLowerCase()) ||
      chk.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase())
  );
  
  
console.log(isContain(ar, "tExt"))
```

Comment: Also need to use a different variable for the callback parameter.